# HTML inserted into QTextEdit does not conform to style sheet

Tags: c++, qt

I have a docked QTextEdit which I am using to emulate a debug terminal in a QT c++ gui, and have it set to a black background with white text.

I am trying to use it to print out error messages from `QXmlSchemaValidator`, but the messages from the schema validator are in html format, and whenever I insert them into the `QTextEdit`, it reverts to it's default font, and I end up with black text on a black background.

The actual message is something like:

```
    <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/'>
    <body>
        <p>Content of element 
            <span class='XQuery-keyword'>minValue</span> does not match its type definition: <span class='XQuery-data'>fu</span> is not valid according to <span class='XQuery-type'>xs:decimal</span>..
        </p>
</body>
</html>
```

using `setAcceptRichText(false)` doesn't solve the problem, and if I use `insertPlainText()` to add text to the `lineEdit`, it removes all the line breaks and leaves the html tags in the error message, which is unacceptable.

Is there some way I can display the HTML rich text, but without blowing away my style sheet font?

Comment: Add some html code to your message to do your text white (font color, basefont tag the best in this case, but I don't sure that Qt supports it) Or this is not good solution for you?

Comment: I'm not actually writting the html message, it's the output of a QAbstractMessageHandler class. I *really* don't want to have to parse the html to insert tags unless I have to.

Comment: Ok, then try next thing:(I don't test it):after you set your html call selectAll(); and after this call setTextColor(Qt::White); Is it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sort of a kludge, but the workaround that I went with was to remove the HTML tags from the schema validator message before adding it to the text edit.

```
QString errorMsg = msg.statusMessage().remove(QRegExp("<[^>]*>"));
textEdit->setText(errorMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my computer. It works perfectly. Use this:

```
edit->setHtml(htmlDescription);
edit->selectAll();
edit->setTextColor(Qt::green);

//Ok, but clear selection
QTextCursor cur = edit->textCursor();
cur.clearSelection();
edit->setTextCursor(cur);
```

Comment: The only problem is the color/background have to be set from the style sheet, not programmatically, so it won't work in my case, but this is a nifty trick.